# Select Maven profile based on JDK update release

Tags: maven, maven-3

A Maven profile can be switched on based on a JDK release, such as 1.7 or 1.8. But I can't find a way to activate a profile based on a JDK update release.

Specifically, I want to be able to have a profile active if JDK 1.8.0_u121 or later is in use. For example, this does not work:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>[1.8.0_u121,]</jdk>
    <activation>
  </profile>
  <additionalparam>--allow-script-in-comments</additionalparam>
</profiles>
```

Any alternative to profiles that achieve the same effect (allowing a property to be set when using 1.8.0_u121 or later will gladly be accepted).

Answer (score 0):

[Maven's Introduction to Build Profiles documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) says:

> The following configuration will trigger the profile when the JDK's
>   version starts with "1.4" (eg. "1.4.0_08", "1.4.2_07", "1.4"):
>
> ```
> <profiles>
>     <profile>
>         <activation>
>             <jdk>1.4</jdk>
>         </activation>
>     </profile>
> </profiles>
> ```

and then mentions that as of Maven 2.1, you can use the [Enforcer Version Range Syntax](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html).

Based on those pieces of documentation, I believe that your activation isn't triggering due to the extra `u`. Perhaps try:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <jdk>[1.8.0_121,)</jdk>
        <activation>
    </profile>
    ...
</profiles>
```

Comment: `Failed to determine activation for profile For input string: "0_121"`

Comment: @Evan I set up a quick reproduction environment, and I was able to activate a profile using `[1.8.0_121,)`, `[1.8.0-121,)`, and `[1.8.0.121,)` which somewhat aligns with the documentation at https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html . I'm using Maven 3.6.3 and JDK 14.0.2. If you have more details about your specific environment, it might warrant opening a new question.

Comment: Maven only checks the first three components of the version. Impossible to activate on a minor version. https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/353d3eaa8f2be47878f584a7da398572b41d90af/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/profile/activation/JdkVersionProfileActivator.java#L141

Comment: @Evan Indeed, that does appear to be what's happening! Great detective work! If you turn that into an answer, I'll upvote it.